# view not displaying the contents of controller array

Tags: php, opencart

I have a controller that pulls data from a model function and stores the data in an array:

```
    $row = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getAllManufacturers();

    $this->data['manufacturer']= array(
        'manufacturer_id'    => $row['manufacturer_id'],
        'name'   => $row['name'],
        'image'       => $row['image']
    );
```

The view simply take the array and iterates the values using a foreach loop and list items. The list items are appearing but not the text value of the array:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($manufacturer as $manuf) {?>
<li><?php echo $manuf['name'];?></li>
<?php }?>
</ul>
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: what is outputted if you put <?php print_r($manufacturer) ?> in the view?

Comment: It outputs the following: Array ( [manufacturer_id] => [name] => [image] => )

Comment: that means that the array values are not being populated.  Could you add the output of print_r($row) in the controller as I think you need to be looping through $row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
$row = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getAllManufacturers();

    $this->data['manufacturer']= array(
        'manufacturer_id'    => $row['manufacturer_id'],
        'name'   => $row['name'],
        'image'       => $row['image']
    );
```

could you try

```
$rows = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getAllManufacturers();
foreach($rows as $row){
    $this->data['manufacturer'][]= array(
        'manufacturer_id'    => $row['manufacturer_id'],
        'name'   => $row['name'],
        'image'       => $row['image']
    );
}
```

Comment: When I try using the modified controller array I am getting an error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Could you give the output of print_r($row) from your original code please

Comment: when placed in the controller I get no out put, but when placed in the  view I get an error saying undefined variable: row

Comment: would you like me to post the model, controller and view code?

Comment: go for it, sounds like a plan

Comment: my model has getAllManufacturers(): public function getAllManufacturers() {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_to_store m2s ON (m.manufacturer_id = m2s.manufacturer_id) WHERE m2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'";
}

Comment: The CONTROLLER:      
$row = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getAllManufacturers();

    $this->data['manufacturer']= array(
        'manufacturer_id'    => $row['manufacturer_id'],
        'name'   => $row['name'],
        'image'       => $row['image']
    );  
  
  
   $this->response->setOutput($this->render());

Comment: THE VIEW:    <ul>
 <?php foreach ($manufacturer as $manuf) {?>
 <li><?php echo $manuf['name'];?></li>
 <?php }?>
 </ul>

Comment: could it be that the method in the model does not have a return statement?

Comment: yeah, there is now execute statement either, you need to execute the sql and then return the rows.  You will then have to use my code above to loop through the array of rows returned.  If you are showing code like you above comments, please just edit your question to add in the extra code, that way it is more readable and doesnt leave a huge pile of comments